# Foxx oauth2 configuration

Tags: arangodb

To play with the demo-sessions app, I've got the oauth2 app mounted on /oauth2 as required.
In arangodb/Foxx doc, the oauth2 endpoints seems to be defined as strings (i.e https://github.com/arangodb-foxx/util-oauth2 )

But when I perform that with correct urls, and try to play with oauth, I've got an error :
...\oauth2\APP\manifest.json\": attribute child \"authEndpoint\" fails because [\"authEndpoint\" must be an object] (was \"[object Object]\").]","...

Oauth endpoints definitions are expected to be objects, not strings. 
So what is the correct configuration for Foxx oauth2 ? 
Thanks for help,

Comment: Could you clarify what version of ArangoDB you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem but the OAuth2 app has been updated for ArangoDB 2.7. You can still install odler versions of the OAuth2 app from the "install from GitHub" dialog, though.

Comment: I use the ArangoDB 2.7 too. The installation seems correct, but in the manifest.json if I change the configuration part :

Comment: Question : does the oauth2 app should be installed in _system database (/oauth2 mount point) or in another database ?  I have installed it in my own database currently.

Comment: In the manifest.json, the configuration is :  ` "configuration": {
    "authEndPoint": "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=user",
    "tokenEndpoint": "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token",
    "refreshEndpoint": "",
    "activeUserEndpoint": "https://api.github.com/user",
    "clientId": "myclientid",
    "clientSecret": "myclientSecret"
  } `    but the same error is released

Comment: 2015-11-03T10:16:32Z [9664] ERROR [ArangoError 3001: Manifest "/opt/ArangoDB 2.7.0/var/lib/arangodb-apps/
_db/people/oauth2/APP/manifest.json": attribute child "authEndPoint" fails because ["authEndPoint" must be an object] (was "[object Object]")
.]\n  at checkManifest (/opt/ArangoDB 2.7.0/share/arangodb/js/server/modules/org/arangodb/foxx/manager.js
:384:11)\n  at validateManifestFile (/opt/ArangoDB 2.7.0/share/arangodb/js/server/modules/org/arangodb/fo
xx/manager.js:439:5)\n  ...

Answer (score 0):

I understand my mistake. In the code of the oauth2 2.0 release, the manifest just references the export.js file. In the previous release (1.2), a providers.js file was supplied and referenced in the manifest. Then in this previous release, it was possible to use different providers (what I want) as described in the 1.2 setup.js. 
    var providers = db._collection(providersName);

I just fetch the files providers.js, and setup.js from 1.2 github tag and configure them  for my configuration, and that's ok.